# how to phrase a condition in if statement properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement, conditional-statements

Okay, I need a div to `fadeIn` on click, but only if a video is not playing, so I thought an if statement was the way to go. I want it so that the fade only happens if a video isn't playing. I'm not sure how to set it up. I tried

```
if($("#myVid") != "playing") {
            $("#MyT").fadeIn(0);
        }
```

I'm probably way off. Can I get some help please?

aaaand, I'm using html5.

Comment: That highly depends on what kind of player you are using. The question is impossible to answer without knowing this.

Comment: what does Playing mean? can you check it out? is there a condition true, false?

Comment: @FrenchiInLA it's a callback, and true/false conditions apply to it....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using the HTML5 `<video>` tag, you can use the following code to determine if the video is currently playing:

```
var elem = $('#myVid')[0]; // get the DOM element
if(!elem.ended && !elem.paused) {
    alert('playing');
}
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLMediaElement for a description of the various properties.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var myvid = document.getElementById('myVid');
if (myvid.error) {
 switch (myvid.error.code) {
   case MEDIA_ERR_ABORTED:
      alert("You stopped the video.");
      break;
   case MEDIA_ERR_NETWORK:
      alert("Network error - please try again later.");
      break;
   case MEDIA_ERR_DECODE:
      alert("Video is broken..");
      break;
   case MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED:
      alert("Sorry, your browser can't play this video.");
      break;
 }
}
```

[source](http://www.chipwreck.de/blog/2010/03/01/html-5-video-dom-attributes-and-events/)